# A valid React element (or null) must be returned. Not sure what the type is to be returned

Tags: react-native

I am trying to follow along this example https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial

and came to the section where the author stated that I can just use this:

return Hello World (Again); in my return statement.

As a result, my code looks like:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');

var styles = ReactNative.StyleSheet.create({
 text: {
 color: 'black',
 backgroundColor: 'white',
 fontSize: 30,
 margin: 80 
}});

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return 'Hello World (Again)';
}


ReactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', function() { return PropertyFinderApp });
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a code formatting issue in the tutorial's website.

Looking at the page source, it seems he meant to write something like:

```
return <ReactNative.Text style={styles.text}>Hello World (Again)</ReactNative.Text>;
```

This is the actual equivalent of the non-JSX example that he provides earlier in the tutorial:

```
return React.createElement(ReactNative.Text, {style: styles.text}, "Hello World!");
```

The string `'Hello World (Again)'`, on its own, is not a valid return value for a `render` function, as the error you got indicates.

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @RichardChen You're very welcome. :) Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be a good idea to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking (and specifically pertinent to this case - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactNative.Text>Hello World (Again)</ReactNative.Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Always remember that you need to return a REACT ELEMENT in your render function.